# Posting From Apple Aperture?

Tags: posts, third-party-applications

When sorting through my images in Apple Aperture I regularly find myself wanting to post one, or a few dozen, of them to one of my WordPress sites.  Does anyone know of an Aperture plugin or some way to create a quick post directly from the app?  If Aperture was written in PHP, I'd be set!

Thanks,

Mark

EDIT: I mistakenly referred to 'Adobe' Aperture.  I really need to make a choice between Lightroom & Aperture, and stick with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this is a matter of Aperture/Lightroom plugins, maybe this Question could be posed in other sites of the Stack:

- [Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/)
- [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)

The Aperture side seems to have less options:

- the only plugin I've found seems outdated, [Pixelpipe](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/30010/pixelpipe-for-aperture)
- [an Applescript](http://nikansell.wordpress.com/2011/03/27/share-your-aperture-images-with-everyone-everywhere/) that may be of use if tweaked.

This Mac blogging app, [Marsedit](http://www.red-sweater.com/marsedit/), may be a solution. Much probably, alternatives exist for other OS.

And the plugins in Lightroom side, which covers Macs and Windows:

- [LR/Blog](http://www.photographers-toolbox.com/products/lrblog.php)
- [NextGEN Gallery Export](http://alloyphoto.com/plugins/nextgen/)
- other [export plugins](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?s=5&from=1&o=desc&cat=278&l=-1&event=productHome&exc=25) that connect to Flicker, Picasa, etc, could be used as a triangulated solution with another WP plugin

All linked solutions are paid and most have a trial option. Just tested LR/Blog and works flawlessly creating a post and uploading/attaching the images.